# Как выделить option в списке Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

Есть такой код:

```
<select name="city" ng-model="formData.city">
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.cities" value="{{key}}">{{value}}      </option>
</select>
```

В переменной `formData.city` номер  `1723` - номер города.

В объекте `data.cities` все города:

```
{1723: "Baru"}
```

Как выделить в списке оптион со значнием `1723`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.formData.city = $scope.data.cities[1723]
```